# GTK+ with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, cmd, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to install the [GTK project](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/) on windows 10, and integrate it with Visual Studio in order to build an app with C.

After following their [tutorial on installation](https://github.com/wingtk/gvsbuild) , I have found myself at step 5 successfully, yet when I open visual studio to try and compile the "[hello world](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/)" type code It doesn't recognise the header

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

and spits out the error

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol 
gtk_window_set_child referenced in function activate
```

and

```
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  test
```

so I went back to [this](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/) page and followed the "Using GTK from MSYS2 packages" section, and again, no cigar.

I continued after these steps by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022995/how-do-i-get-gtk-running-with-visual-studio-2019), and while the IDE now recognises the header and autocompletes, it seems that I'm still doing something wrong ...

The errors from the console are (after trying a few ways of executing the code)

```
D:\CDev\test>gcc -o test test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs 
gtk4`
gcc: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: error: gtk4`: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '--cflags'
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '--libs'

D:\CDev\test>gcc test.c
test.c:1:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or 
  directory
     1 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

I'm wondering if this is relevant ...

```
{
   "cmake.configureSettings": {
     "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "[vcpkg root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
    }
}
```

but am hesitant to start messing around with cmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remember:

```
`
```

rather than

```
'
```

in the cmd.

PLEASE use this [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) if you come across this page!